# Cannot SVN checkout when anon-access = none

Tags: linux, unix, svn

When I have

```
anon-access = write
```

Everything works fine. When I change svnserve.conf to:

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
```

And uncomment password-db and authz-db AND add user in authz with rw AND put username/password in passwd, nothing works. Eclipse keeps giving me a "Cannot map the project with svn provider" error.

I have given all the files under conf 777.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Could you try the commandline svn client? The errors from the commandline client are far more "googleable". Example:

    svn checkout http://full.path.to/your/svn/repository dir

Answer (score 1):

I commented out

```
authz-db
```

in svnserve.conf. Everything OK now.